# What is a word to say "use as a test case"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Papers often use one example throughout as their ongoing example. Similarly, it is possible to focus on one particular case and show a broader claim by using that case.

I remember there was a really nice verb for *using x at a test case*, or perhaps *x serves as a use case*.

I tried a thesaurus searching for *exemplify* (which is close, but not exactly right) and some other searches ... but none of these helped much.

An example sentence might be:

> Testing food in general, we *verbify* eggs.

or

> Eggs *verbify* food in our context.

More elaborate examples:

> Using the RR dataset as a test case, we investigate how different aspects of metric design affect the computation cost.

> We perform an analysis study on efficiency, using the popular RR dataset as a test case.

> As a test case for investigating dataset efficiency, we analyze the results of RR.

Comment: Poor example sentences. In these sorts of questions it is usually the example sentences that offer the best guidance.  Please improve the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your second example, *epitomise* could be used:

> **epitomise** [verb]: be a perfect example of.
>
> - *the company epitomized the problems faced by British industry*

[[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=epitomise+meaning&sca_esv=556714279&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=PfvZZM7VIYaYhbIPi_yC-Ac&ved=0ahUKEwiO6P-O8tuAAxUGTEEAHQu-AH8Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=epito)]

Hence

- *Testing of eggs epitomises food testing in general.*

With the looser usage licensed by Oxford's example (and note the alternative spelling), 'to *provide* / *furnish [one] with* the perfect example of', with metonymy ('company' for 'company's problems', 'eggs' for 'testing of eggs')

- *Eggs epitomise food testing in general.*

[Dictionary,com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/epitomise) explicitly licenses this broadened sense of 'epitomise' [emphasis mine]:

> **epitomize** [verb] (used with object),
>
> **to contain or represent in small compass**; serve as a typical example of; typify:
>
> - This meadow epitomizes the beauty of the whole area.